# Никак не получается установить пакеты через pip3 на python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

pip3 не видит пакеты. Пытаюсь установить пакеты командой pip3 install имя_пакета, или python3 -m pip install имя_пакета, но пакеты не устанавливаются. В начале несолько раз появляется ошибка

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/librosa/
```

потом в конце ошибка

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement librosa<br>
ERROR: No matching distribution found for librosa <br>
```

Версия Ubuntu 18.04, python 3.6, pip 20.3.1

Comment: попробуйте обновить его

Comment: Я его установил командой sudo apt install python3-pip. Установилась версия pip 9.  Потом обновил командой python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip до версии pip 20.3.1

Comment: Все это я делаю на удаленном сервере

Comment: @Soft это с одним пакетом происходит или со всеми?

Comment: Пробовал с tensorflow==1.15, librosa, matplotlib не устанавливаются. Также пробовал установить numpy, в первых 2 попытках тоже не установилась, на третий раз кое как установилась.

Comment: Посмотрите путь к пакетам питона 'print(site.getsitepackages())), а потом 'pip3 -V'. Кстати проверьте вариант просто pip. Ввиду того что 2 версию питона убирают из системы бывают нюансы. Ну и ошибка у вас ругается на качество инета.

Comment: Интернет нормальный у меня 30 м/бит. Сейчас переустановил все Ubuntu 18.04, вместе с ним установился python 3.6. Затем установил python3-pip и обновил его. И после этого получилось установить numpy, librosa, в начале даже tensorflow скачивал. Скачал 300 мбайт и выскочило много ошибок. После этого не получается установить matplotlib, tqdm и т.д. Не находит пакеты